# How to set the trigger when the value does not equal to a specified value in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

i would like to change the background of a ListBox to red if the SelectedIndex of ListBox greater than -1. but in xaml i only can use "=".

```
<ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
```

What i want is:

```
<ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value>"-1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
```

Is it possible to do this in xaml?

Comment: XAML has no support for less than or greater than operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the other way round:

```
<ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
```

Comment: It is a good idea, but still does not suit me, eg.
<ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Style>

Comment: Is this supposed to tell me anything? Please edit your question in case you forgot some details.

Comment: In fact i would like to disable the selection of ListBox in xaml

Comment: "*disable the selection*" is a completely different thing. You probably wanted to use an ItemsControl instead of a ListBox.